# Jenkins pipeline cutted log

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I got a pipeline jobs that contains over 30 stages.
Recently I noticed that log is cut in 1 of 10 builds, the log file on server cut as well.

Full log contains log for all 30 stages while cut log contains logs for 12-16 stages.

Redirecting the log to file solving the issue, but I need those logs on console.

Any one had same issues ? Any Ideas how to fix ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error with server HD